# Appending incoming csv files in Python to a master data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have these data exports that are populating every hour in a particular directory, and i'm hoping to have a script that reads all the files and appends them into one master dataframe in Python. Only issue is, since they are populating every hour, I don't want to append existing or already added csv files to the master dataframe.

I'm very new to Python, and so far have only been able to load all the files in the directory and append them all, using the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = os.environ['HOME'] + "/file_location/"
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"name_of_files*.csv"))
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in allFiles), sort=False)
```

With the above code, it looks into the file_location and imports any files with the name "name_of_files" & uses a wildcard as the tail of each of the files will be different.

I could continue to do this, but i'm literally going to have hundreds of files and don't want to import them all and append/concat them each and every hour. To avoid this i'd like to have that master data frame mentioned above and just have new csv files that populate each hour to be automatically appended to that existing master df.

Again super new to Python, so not even sure what to do next. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: documentation is your friend: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: You could use a loop that would do the repetitive task for you. The loop can be a separate script or you can add in this same script itself.

Comment: Can't you delete the csvs' once they are appended to the master dataframe?

Comment: Could do that @AjayShah, or potentially change the name each time, but just looking for the most efficient way as possible. Would anyone know the code to automatically change the name or move the files after they have been appended?

Comment: You can use the OS module in Python to do a lot of things such as copy, move or even rename the files. Try it out. If you don't need them later as they would consume your hard disk, best would be to delete. Thoughts?

Comment: @AjayShah I'm adding them to an Amazon S3 bucket, so storage isn't much of an issue as I have a tonne of space there. Will try out the renaming strategy, thanks for the help